# Sum overflow TimeDeltas in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, timedelta

While trying to sum across timedeltas in pandas, it seems to work for a slice but not the whole column.

```
>> d.ix[0:100, 'VOID-DAYS'].sum()
Timedelta('2113 days 00:00:00')

>> d['VOID-DAYS'].sum()


ValueError: overflow in timedelta operation
```

Comment: That means your sum values has exceed the max limits of a timedelta: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects how many rows do you have?

Answer (score 8):

If `VOID-DAYS` represents an integer number of days, convert the Timedeltas into integers:

```
df['VOID-DAYS'] = df['VOID-DAYS'].dt.days
```

---

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'VOID-DAYS': pd.to_timedelta(np.ones((106752,)), unit='D')})
try:
    print(df['VOID-DAYS'].sum())
except ValueError as err:
    print(err)
    # overflow in timedelta operation


df['VOID-DAYS'] = df['VOID-DAYS'].dt.days
print(df['VOID-DAYS'].sum())
# 106752
```

---

If the Timedeltas include seconds or smaller units, then use

```
df['VOID-DAYS'] = df['VOID-DAYS'].dt.total_seconds()
```

to convert the value to a float.

---

Pandas Timedeltas (Series and TimedeltaIndexes) store all timedeltas as ints compatible with NumPy's `timedelta64[ns]` dtype. This dtype uses 8-byte ints to store the timedelta in nanoseconds.

The largest number of days representable in this format is

```
In [73]: int(float(np.iinfo(np.int64).max) / (10**9 * 3600 * 24))
Out[73]: 106751
```

Which is why

```
In [74]: pd.Series(pd.to_timedelta(np.ones((106752,)), unit='D')).sum()
ValueError: overflow in timedelta operation
```

raises a `ValueError`, but

```
In [75]: pd.Series(pd.to_timedelta(np.ones((106751,)), unit='D')).sum()
Out[75]: Timedelta('106751 days 00:00:00')
```

does not.