# Sum of Timedeltas column in Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, sum, timedelta

A similar question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4049825/how-to-get-the-sum-of-timedelta-in-python) before

But when I tried all the available solutions it was giving me error.

Code:

```
print sum(data['Activity_Duration'],datetime.timedelta())  
#import operator  
#print reduce(operator.add, data['Activity_Duration'])
```

Error:

> OverflowError
>
> 1 #print sum(data['Activity_Duration'],datetime.timedelta())
>   2 import operator
>   ----> 3 print reduce(operator.add, data['Activity_Duration'])
>
> OverflowError: long too big to convert

Am i missing something or can we come up with a more scalable solution?

**Info:** My data has 436746 rows.

I am working on 8 gig machine and data size is 650MB

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sum.html):

```
print (df['Activity_Duration'].sum())
```

Sample:

```
import pandas as pd

start = pd.to_datetime('2015-02-24')
end = pd.to_datetime('2016-04-25')
rng = pd.date_range(start, end, freq='6D')

start = pd.to_datetime('2015-02-26')
end = pd.to_datetime('2016-04-27')
rng1 = pd.date_range(start, end, freq='6D')

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date1': rng, 'Date2': rng1})  

df['Activity_Duration'] = df.Date2 - df.Date1
print (df)
        Date1      Date2  Activity_Duration
0  2015-02-24 2015-02-26             2 days
1  2015-03-02 2015-03-04             2 days
2  2015-03-08 2015-03-10             2 days
3  2015-03-14 2015-03-16             2 days
4  2015-03-20 2015-03-22             2 days
5  2015-03-26 2015-03-28             2 days
6  2015-04-01 2015-04-03             2 days
7  2015-04-07 2015-04-09             2 days
8  2015-04-13 2015-04-15             2 days
9  2015-04-19 2015-04-21             2 days
...
...


print (df['Activity_Duration'].sum())
144 days 00:00:00
```

If need output in `float`:

```
import numpy as np

df['Activity_Duration'] = (df.Date2 - df.Date1) / np.timedelta64(1, 'D')
print (df)
        Date1      Date2  Activity_Duration
0  2015-02-24 2015-02-26                2.0
1  2015-03-02 2015-03-04                2.0
2  2015-03-08 2015-03-10                2.0
3  2015-03-14 2015-03-16                2.0
4  2015-03-20 2015-03-22                2.0
...
...
...

print (df['Activity_Duration'].sum())
144.0
```

Another solution is [`dt.days`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.days.html) - output is `int`:

```
print (df['Activity_Duration'].dt.days.sum())
144
```

[Timedelta limitations](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timedeltas.html#timedelta-limitations).

Comment: I would still like the output in timedelta like your first suggestion but I am getting this error now - 

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-62b843ee98a4> in <module>()
      2 #import operator
      3 #print reduce(operator.add, data['Activity_Duration'])
----> 4 data['Activity_Duration'].sum()

ValueError: overflow in timedelta operation

Comment: I think it means output is too big number. what return second suggestion?

Comment: Sum is more as `106751`, it is max value of timedelta - [see](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36766546/sum-overflow-timedeltas-in-python-pandas)

Comment: okk I understand thanks for that. So is there a way I can get this computation done?

Comment: I think solution is my second suggestion or `df['Activity_Duration'].dt.days.sum()`

Comment: `df['Activity_Duration'].dt.days.sum()` worked like magic! thanks!!! Please edit your answer so that it includes this and I will accept :)